# SQL Server : can anyone simplify this logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is as below

```
declare @row_id int = 2
declare @last_row_id int  =(select MAX(Row_ID) from dbo.Source)

create table #source  (
    Row_ID float null,
      [Document] [nvarchar](255) NULL,    
      [ITEMCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,    
      [Text] [nvarchar](255) NULL)

while(@row_id<=(@last_row_id))
begin

declare @Document nvarchar(255)
declare @itemcode nvarchar(255)

select @itemcode=ITEMCode,@Document=Document from dbo.Source where Row_ID=@row_id


if ((@itemcode='' or @itemcode is null ) )
select @itemcode=ITEMCode,@Document=Document from #source where Row_ID=@row_id-1

insert into #source
select Row_ID,@Document,@itemcode,[Text]
from dbo.Source where Row_ID=@row_id

print @row_id

set @row_id= @row_id+1

end

select * from #source
drop table #source
```

Presently my table has 347000 rows .its taking more than a hour to get me final output . how can this query made faster . Can anyone help ?

Requirement :

Source :

```
  Row_ID    Document    ITEMCode     Text                   
    2      10223         20235       aaaa
    3                                    bbbb
    4                                    cccc
    5      10278         202475      xxxx
    6                                    yyyy
    7                                    yyy
```

Output should be :

```
 Row_ID  Document  ITEMCode Text    
   2       10223     20235  aaaa
   3       10223     20235  bbbb
   4       10223     20235  cccc
   5       10278    202475  xxxx
   6       10278    202475  yyyy
   7       10278    202475  yyy
```

Comment: Why are you SELECTing from #source before there's anything in it?

Comment: i dont select when there is anything in it . In first record of dbo.Source , ITEMCode is not empty or n ull . so that ststement wont execute for first time . when loop goes 2 nd time der #source has data in it

Comment: You'll probably get better responses if you describe what the overall purpose of this code is.  It's hard to read code.

Comment: I think I understand now. So, you're getting the data from either the current row or the previous row of Source, right? If so, you don't need a WHILE loop. You can instead self-join Source, matching Row to Row-1. Make sense?

Comment: Any reason why Row_Id in #Source is a float, when it appears to be an int in dbo.source? I'd echo Cheran's suggestion that you give an idea of what you are trying to achieve. You should really try and avoid RBAR operations in favour of SET operations -http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/

Comment: @ John Pick just see ma latest edit . you will get to see wht is der in source table and what should be the output

Comment: @Mr Moose no significance to float . dat can be even int . in ma db its like dat . so jus posted

Comment: Is there any reason not to store the values for each line? because it will still use the same memory. So instead of doing something that would require a recursive join (that is not easily possible), just use your code and update your rows with the values you need in there.

Comment: This is something I would do in a spreadsheet using formulas :) e.g. `=IF(A2="",A1,A2)` etc. If it ain't relational data then transform it **before** putting it in a relational database! Transforming using SQL is a fun challenge but ultimately the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though above specified queries might work , I wrote a macro in excel  which we quire fast n got the output in less than 5 min

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH
  Source (Row_ID, Document, ITEMCode, Text) AS (
    SELECT 2, '10223', '20235' , 'aaaa' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, ''     , ''      , 'bbbb' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, ''     , ''      , 'cccc' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '10278', '202475', 'xxxx' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, '10278', '202475', 'yyyy' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, '10278', '202475', 'yyy'
  ),
  ranked AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Row_ID)
    FROM Source
  ),
  filled AS (
    SELECT
      Row_ID,
      Document,
      ITEMCode,
      Text,
      rnk
    FROM ranked
    WHERE rnk = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      r.Row_ID,
      Document = ISNULL(NULLIF(r.Document, ''), f.Document),
      ITEMCode = ISNULL(NULLIF(r.ITEMCode, ''), f.ITEMCode),
      r.Text,
      r.rnk
    FROM ranked r
      INNER JOIN filled f ON r.rnk = f.rnk + 1
  )
SELECT
  Row_ID,
  Document,
  ITEMCode,
  Text
FROM filled
```

Output:

```
Row_ID      Document ITEMCode Text
----------- -------- -------- ----
2           10223    20235    aaaa
3           10223    20235    bbbb
4           10223    20235    cccc
5           10278    202475   xxxx
6           10278    202475   yyyy
7           10278    202475   yyy
```

If `Document` and `ITEMCode` are actually integers, not strings, the above script would work, but generally it would be better to change these two lines:

```
Document = ISNULL(NULLIF(r.Document, ''), f.Document),
ITEMCode = ISNULL(NULLIF(r.ITEMCode, ''), f.ITEMCode),
```

like this:

```
Document = ISNULL(NULLIF(r.Document, 0), f.Document),
ITEMCode = ISNULL(NULLIF(r.ITEMCode, 0), f.ITEMCode),
```